# how to trigger number validation in Unobtrusive manually

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i have a model

```
[Required]
[RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]+$", ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Number only")]
public string name{get;set;}
```

I need to check that when user enters data in this field on view page it should fire this number validation on keypress event of textbox.

```
        $('#UserName').keypress(function (event) {
        if (event.which != 8 && isNaN(String.fromCharCode(event.which))) {

            $(this).parents('form').validate().element(this);
            event.preventDefault(); //stop character from entering input
        }

    });
```

Comment: Why is your property typeof `string` (instead of `int`)?

Comment: it is string but on view page i need only numer in this.I used this on keypress.  $(this).parents('form').validate().element(this); but it fires required validation first but i have to call number validation.

Comment: If you only want an `int` then the property should be `int`! jquery validation is lazy, meaning it wont trigger the first time until you modify the controls value and tab out of it. Thereafter if you tab back in it will be validated on keyup. The easiest way to handle this is to include a script that handles the controls `keypress()` event to prevent any input except numbers

Comment: i used the code for keypress but i have to fire unobtrusive validation for this manually.please check code above.

Comment: No, I mean the script should prevent the user entering anything other than a number - so there is no need to ever validate it. Something like `$('#UserName').keypress(function (e) { var k = e.keyCode; if (!(k > 47 && k < 58)) { window.event.returnValue = false; }; });`

Comment: i have to call unobtrusive js when user press key

Comment: i have to call a specific validation on this not all of the validation on this like i have to call only number validation not required

Comment: If you use the script in my previous comment you do not have to call validate - the user can only ever enter a number so its always valid - there is nothing to check

Comment: i have to show message also over there but i don't want to create custom things for this i have to call unobtrusive  call for this

Comment: Then write your own validation frame work.

Answer (score 0):

You may make an AJAX call to the action method to validate textbox field. You will then be able to handle the response in the 'success' callback of the ajax call.

```
$('#idOfTextbox').keypress(function(e) {
        $.ajax({
        //.. Your values go here...
        });
});
```

Note Keypress will be call every time key is press you may use blur  `$('#idOfTextbox').blur(function(e){})` this fire on focus lost